# Rails help needed - unable to push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Unable to push Hartl chapter 5 rails to Heroku. Can find any answers when searching error via Google. Details...

Error:

```
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
!
!     Precompiling assets failed.
!

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Heroku log:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:quiet-beyond-1969.git'
OMITTED_PC_NAME:sample_app OMITTED_USERNAME $ heroku logs
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076108+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076110+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076111+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076119+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076131+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076123+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076134+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076124+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076155+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076125+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076156+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/rub
y/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076130+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076159+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076127+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076128+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076116+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076118+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076160+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-13T11:07:43.076121+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-13T11:07:43.074007+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/contact" for 24.209.204.140 at 2014-05-13 11:07:43 +0000
2014-05-13T11:07:43.393773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quiet-beyond-1969.herokuapp.com request_id=71bfd62e-09a9-49b0-81ce-1db83645ec87 fwd="24.209.204.140" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-05-13T11:07:55.947210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static_pages/contact host=quiet-beyond-1969.herokuapp.com request_id=7fe1479d-3624-40de-921a-48244240c973 fwd="24.209.204.140" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=1545
2014-05-13T11:07:55.927574+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/static_pages/contact" for 24.209.204.140 at 2014-05-13 11:07:55 +0000
2014-05-13T11:07:55.932959+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/contact.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
2014-05-13T11:07:55.934322+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-05-13T11:07:55.930303+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#contact as HTML
2014-05-13T11:07:56.292382+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quiet-beyond-1969.herokuapp.com request_id=9c724802-1937-449d-908f-caa71ee4fa1d fwd="24.209.204.140" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-05-13T12:09:32.928745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-05-13T12:09:32.929319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867617+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867618+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867615+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867612+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867621+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867623+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867625+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867626+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867742+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-13 12:09:35] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867806+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-13 12:09:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867860+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867607+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867608+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867613+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867597+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-13 12:09:35] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867605+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867610+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-05-13T12:09:35.867620+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-05-13T12:09:37.322432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-05-13T12:09:35.371241+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-05-14T22:48:03.955115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2014-05-14T22:48:03.954820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-05-14T22:48:10.611841+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-14 22:48:10] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-05-14T22:48:10.611862+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-14 22:48:10] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-05-14T22:48:10.612454+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-14 22:48:10] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=7642
2014-05-14T22:48:12.336196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static_pages/contact host=quiet-beyond-1969.herokuapp.com request_id=12a3e997-f281-4003-8e92-2a134adb632b fwd="64.233.172.211" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=153ms status=200 bytes=1585
2014-05-14T22:48:12.419986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quiet-beyond-1969.herokuapp.com request_id=74aae286-1214-4943-8b36-3511a44d036b fwd="64.233.172.211" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=228
2014-05-14T22:48:12.185854+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-05-14T22:48:12.185857+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-05-14T22:48:12.185852+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:7642
2014-05-14T22:48:12.300409+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#contact as HTML
2014-05-14T22:48:12.326506+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 25.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-05-14T22:48:12.185856+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-05-14T22:48:12.185859+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/static_pages/contact" for 64.233.172.211 at 2014-05-14 22:48:12 +0000
2014-05-14T22:48:12.185817+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-05-14T22:48:12.303808+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/contact.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
2014-05-14T22:48:07.499920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 7642 -e production`
2014-05-14T22:48:11.046152+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-05-14T23:55:23.751138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-05-14T23:55:23.750586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102715+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102713+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102716+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102711+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102729+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102762+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-14 23:55:27] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102865+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-14 23:55:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102886+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102708+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102700+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-14 23:55:27] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102718+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102728+00:00 app[web.1]:  bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102723+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102725+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102726+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102710+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102720+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-05-14T23:55:27.102721+00:00 app[web.1]:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-05-14T23:55:26.472850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-05-14T23:55:28.363695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-05-20T11:25:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-20T11:25:23+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-05-20T11:29:36+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-20T11:29:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-05-20T21:56:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-20T21:56:35+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2014-05-21T10:35:08+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-05-21T10:35:25+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
```

Any ideas. I can't seem to find anything on Google. The app runs fine locally.

[Repo on Github](http://github.com/freqn/s_app)

Comment: [Have you precompiled your assets locally??](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to precompile your assets locally and then add -A, commit, and push.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline